# Programming Square payment and in Flutter App with Backend

Tags: flutter, dart, payment-gateway, square-connect, square

I have got the following code from Square explaining the dart/flutter side of code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:square_in_app_payments/models.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// Replace this with the server host you create, if you have your own server running
// e.g. https://server-host.com
String chargeServerHost = "https://myappexample.herokuapp.com";
String chargeUrl = "$chargeServerHost/chargeForCookie";

class ChargeException implements Exception {
  String errorMessage;
  ChargeException(this.errorMessage);
}

Future<void> chargeCard(CardDetails result) async {
  var body = jsonEncode({"nonce": result.nonce}); // ({"nonce": result.nonce,"amount":1, "currency":"GBP"})
  http.Response response;
  try {
    response = await http.post(chargeUrl, body: body, headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    });
  } on SocketException catch (ex) {
    print(ex.message);
    throw ChargeException(ex.message);
  }

  var responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return;
  } else {
    print(response.statusCode.toString());
    throw ChargeException(responseBody["errorMessage"]);
  }
}
```

For backend I followed these steps here: https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-server-quickstart

I do not have any experience in server side programming so only following how I am understanding the steps. With this setup I am able to send the nonce to the chargecard method and then get bad request 400 error.

I need help in resolving this to work fine.

Comment: If you login to Heroku, are you able to view the logs and see what errors are happening? The logs can be found by going to: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your-app-name/logs, or by logging into Heroku > choosing your app > clicking "More" dropdown in the upper-right > "View Logs".

Comment: The logs are as follows: 2019-09-03T19:58:39.669137+00:00 app[web.1]: [Error] Status:400, Messages: [
    "code": "INVALID_VALUE",
   "detail": "This business can only process payments in GBP but amount was provided in USD.",
2019-09-03... app[web.1]:     "field": "order.line_items[0].base_price_money.currency",
2019-09-03T1..p[web.1]:     "category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR"
2019-0...0 app[web.1]:   }
2019-0...pp[web.1]: ]        and I have tried with the response body like :   var body = jsonEncode({"nonce": result.nonce,"amount":1, "currency":"GBP"});

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. The sample Heroku server that Square provides has the currency hardcoded to "USD" (https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-server-quickstart/blob/master/index.js#L35). You'll need to fork the server repo, change the "USD" to "GBD" and redeploy to Heroku so it has that change. You could of course also update it to accept the currency like your above currency, but it will need to be changed as well (something like: `requestBody.currency`).

Comment: Thanks Stephen! Are you referring to this code  `const createOrderRequest = {
      idempotency_key: crypto.randomBytes(12).toString('hex'),
      order: {
        line_items: [
          {
            name: "Cookie ",
            quantity: "1",
            base_price_money: {
              amount: 100,
              currency: "USD"
          }
        }
        ]
      }
    }` Is there a tutorial on how do I change things on Heroku? Secondly this is raising one question in my mind which is why is this hard coded in the server. I am not using sandbox for this but my real key.

Comment: The easiest thing would just be cloning your Heroku repo to your local computer (https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your-app-name/deploy/heroku-git), make the change on your computer, and deploy it back to Heroku (instructions on the link I just provided). We hardcoded it on the server since it's meant to be just a quick-start and easy to get up and running. You'll probably want to do more sophisticated things once you get up and running.

Comment: Thanks. So, I tried the steps on my dashboard page. I get the following warning: `MacPro:desktop D$ heroku git:clone -a MyProject
Cloning into 'MyProject'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.`

Comment: I'm not sure what happened? This is the project that you deployed via this repo (https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-server-quickstart)? I just tested it out and it cloned successfully. For more assistance (and quicker response) feel free to join Square's Slack channel: https://squ.re/2Hks3YE